# jQuery: Unbinding transtionend event

Tags: jquery, transition, transitionend

I want an object to move first left, then up, every time I call this action. It works fine the first time, but on second time, the object moves diagonally not in steps.

Currently I have this:

```
myObject.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ 
    myObject.css("left", 100);
    myObject.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
        myObject.css("top", 50);
    });
});
```

1. Any other suggestions on how to achieve stepped animation?
2. How do I unbind both of those "bindings" so it run like first time on every action?

Comment: Don't use `.bind()`, it's deprecated. You should be using `.on()` and `.off()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `.animate()`?

Comment: @Barmar what would be the difference?

Comment: Isn't animate more cpu heavy?

Comment: I don't know, but most of the time you should use the clearest code, and only worry about efficiency if it turns out to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the old bindings with `.off()`. Otherwise, you're accumulating multiple event handlers, and they all run whenever one of the events occurs.

```
myObject.off("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd")
  .on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd"),
  function() {
    myObject.css("left", 100);
    myObject.off("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd")
      .on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd"),
      function() {
        myObject.css("top", 50);
      });
});
```